# Link to blog appearing when logged out, but not when logged in?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I had the good fortune two days ago of checking the site on a different computer, logged out from my account. Because of this, I noticed the link to the site blog right up there with review, chat, main, and faq. Hurray, 100% more official! However, when I logged in, the link simply vanished. Same thing on my own computer: when I'm logged in, I can't see it, but when I log out, the blog link is there.

[image: logged out]

[image: logged in]

Is this the intended site behavior, or is this a bug?

Comment: The link in the footer always leads to the Gaming blog now (on the main site, not this meta), also when you're logged in

Answer (score 5):

There was a Meta post somewhere... somwhere... [apparently it's on Meta Stack Overflow but not as its own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90208/hey-we-want-some-attention-for-the-super-user-blog/92025#92025) (thanks Ivo Flipse!).

They added the blog link to the top bar. However, there's *a lot* of options up there for a logged in user, and they simply didn't have the real estate to add that on, so it's only there for logged out users. This is intentional.

Comment: It was on meta.SU but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Here's the link @Grace: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90208/hey-we-want-some-attention-for-the-super-user-blog/92025#92025

Comment: @Ivo Curiously, this makes badp wrong in the sense it was never on Meta Super User, but right in the sense that it was meta Super User that it could be found.